# Failed to get list of windows of a process on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, sandbox

I am trying to access list of windows of a process in MAC OS X (Mountain Lion) from a SandBoxing enabled application. But AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue API fails with `Error "kAXErrorCannotComplete"`. It is working if i disable "Sandboxing"

```
AXUIElementRef app = AXUIElementCreateApplication([[CGWindowInfo objectForKey:(NSString*)kCGWindowOwnerPID] unsignedIntValue]);

if (app) {

    NSArray* windows = nil;
    AXError error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(app, kAXWindowsAttribute, (CFTypeRef*)&windows);

}
```

windows array is being returned nil.

Your help in this regards is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
 CGWindowListCreate( kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly,    kCGNullWindowID);
 CFArrayRef aWindowsInfoArrayRef = CGWindowListCreateDescriptionFromArray(aArrayRef);
```

Then filter the array for a specific application's windows